# Eclipse Git Repository Branch Hash not updating

Tags: eclipse, git

I been trying to follow this tutorial on using Eclipse and GITHUB when multiple people are writing within the same project using branches.  I believe I understand everything and how its working.. HOWEVER.. my hash isn't updating like the video is showing on local branches.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfeqnernMmE

If you look at minute 3:50 - 3:60 you will see him do a COMMIT and it will then update on the local branch and generates a new HASH etc...(text in grey next to ChangeDefaults in the video) My Eclipse won't freaking do this.  I make a change exactly like he does, I do a commit, but my Hash's and comment text (all the text in GREY) don't update or change at all.  They same the exact same as it was before and I'm not seeing any onscreen errors or anything.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there were 2 things I was doing wrong.

1) I wasn't using the correct Repository when I was modifying things.  I had the wrong "Project" open.

2) I was missing an update and had to update my GIT inside my eclipse.